# Convert a list of floats in a df column into percentage and round off to 1 decimal digit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to get percentage & roundoff the list of values in a df column.
I have a df as

```
id       name            value
============================================
1         AA        [0.0012, 0.0022, 0.365]
2         BB        [0.0412, 0.822, 0.3]
3         CC        [0.692, 0.0002, 0.56]
```

Is there a way to the above df to

```
id       name            value
============================================
1         AA        [0.1, 0.2, 36.5]
2         BB        [4.1, 82.2, 3]
3         CC        [69.2, 0.0, 56]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
    'value': [
        [0.0012, 0.0022, 0.365],
        [0.0412, 0.822, 0.3],
        [0.692, 0.0002, 0.56]
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def convert_to_percentage(value_list):
    return [round(val * 100, 1) for val in value_list]

df['value'] = df['value'].apply(convert_to_percentage)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id name              value
0   1   AA   [0.1, 0.2, 36.5]
1   2   BB  [4.1, 82.2, 30.0]
2   3   CC  [69.2, 0.0, 56.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use create a simple function which takes the values from the "df" and converts them into percentages and rounds them accordingly.

Here is an example for the same:

```
# Function to calculate percentage and round off
def percentage_and_round(value_list):
    return [round(val * 100, 1) for val in value_list]

# Apply the function to the "value" column
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(percentage_and_round)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `nested list comprehension`:

```
df['value'] = [[round(y*100, 1) for y in x] for x in df['value']]
```

Output:

```
   id name              value
0   1   AA   [0.1, 0.2, 36.5]
1   2   BB  [4.1, 82.2, 30.0]
2   3   CC  [69.2, 0.0, 56.0]
```